# Can a dock window dock anywhere or just on top, bottom, left, right?

Tags: wpf, winforms, dock

I need use a lot of such windows in my UIs (WPF, WinForms)
say a label with text "Settings", When mouse hovers it, a window will show up and when mouse moves away, the window disappear. The label and the window should line up looks as if they were a tab control with the label being header, the window being tab item. 
The label can be in anywhere of main UI. 
I am thinking of dock window.
I just start so not sure if my question makes sense. 
My understanding is I can use nested dock windows, like use a dock window inside a panel,  the panel is one child of parent panel/window. but nested panels are not quite straight/easy. so I wonder if a dock window can dock anywhere? thanks

Comment: It is usually better to explain what you are trying to accomplish rather than what technique you have decided to use. See [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why not use a docking library instead of creating your own?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you could be to use an existing library and don't reinvent the wheel. Please see [THIS](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) excellent docking library, possible it offers all requirements that you need. Its name is AvalonDock and it is used by several big projects. An example is SharpDevelop, this software use the AvalonDock library. Hope this could be helpful to you...